# Question about onto function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I came across this question when doing an online test about onto function. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2uva.jpg) the question and the correct answer given. However, for $b = -1$ $\in$ $B$ $\{-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ..\}$ I can't find any $a$ $\in$ $\{0, 1, 2, 3, ..\}$ such that $f(a)=b=-1$.

What I am misunderstanding here? Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: What is $f(0)$?

Comment: Floor (x) is the largest integer not exceeding x. In the pre-computer age it was written [x].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're using the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), so $f(0)=\lfloor-1/2\rfloor=-1$

They also give a helpful hint that if $a=2(b+1)$ then $f(a)=b$, so checking $2(-1+1)=0$ you can see that $f(0)=-1$

Comment: Actually I didn't know about the floor / ceiling function things. Thank you very much for clarifying it for me.